# Install custom plugin for Kibana on AWS ElasticSearch Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I want to know if it is possible to add a custom plugin for Kibana running on an AWS instance as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-plugins.html).

From the command line we can type,

`bin/kibana-plugin install some-plugin`

But, In case of AWS ElasticSearch Service, there is no command prompt/terminal as it is just a service and we don't get to SSH to it. We just have the management console. How to add a custom plugin for kibana in this scenario then?

Comment: Do you have access to the plugin directory?

Comment: @doctorlove I can't access the instance, as it just gives me a url and nothing else. Hence, unable to SSH to it. I maybe wrong. Just checking on that. I would've copied it to the folder if can access.

Answer (score 1):

From the AWS [Elasticsearch Supported Plugins](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-plugins.html) page:

> Amazon ES comes prepackaged with several plugins that are available
>   from the Elasticsearch community. Plugins are automatically deployed
>   and managed for you.

The page referenced above has all the plugins supported on each ES version.

Side note, Kibana is installed and fully managed, but it runs as a Node.js application (not as a plugin).